# Mongoose Schema pre hook not working in Express Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on an Express + TypeScript server using Mongoose as the ORM. I want to use pre save hook in the model.

```
import { NextFunction } from "express";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { Schema, Document, model, Model } from "mongoose";

interface UserDocument extends Document {
    // fields //
}

const userSchema = new Schema<UserDocument, Model<UserDocument>>({
    // fields //
});

userSchema.pre<UserDocument>("save", async function (this: UserDocument, next: NextFunction) {
    const user = this;
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
    try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);

        user.password = hash;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
export const User = model<UserDocument>("User", userSchema);
```

The above code is giving me following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '"save"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RegExp | "insertMany"'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(413, 5): The last overload is declared here.
```

I tried to use regex /save/ but then the call back was giving error.
Please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.